# Statistics or resources: which gets disabled first (more often than others)? Images or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am creating a new website and this question came up, statistically, including all browsers (phone browsers as well), which gets disabled more often? Images, Javascript, or CSS? Reason Im looking for an answer is to design the image-replacement technique that covers the most recurrung scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource: [W3Schools Browser stats](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) (JavaScript stats at the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is disabled more often. Why?

- Mobile browsers
- AdBlock Plus
- Some firewalls block JavaScript
- Paranoid users

Comment: Ayyash asked for statistics. [citation needed]

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's hard to tell. Disable images for saving bandwidth while disable javascript for security. I think most users will disable javascript while keeping images.